# adding nokaslr to kernel commandline

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

I'm trying to debug linux kernel using qemu and gdb. The problem is that gdb won't stop at breakpoint. I've searched about it and found that turning kASLR off may help, because kASLR confuses gdb.

> -- Install that kernel on the guest.
>
> > +- Install that kernel on the guest, turn off KASLR by adding "nokaslr" to
> >      the kernel command line .

now I don't know what it means to add nokaslr to command line and the way to do that. Any idea?

Comment: you should check if you have `kaslr` in your kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to pass a command line to kernel depends on how you start it. If you instruct QEMU to directly boot particular kernel using `-kernel` and `-initrd` options, then you need the `-append` option to specify command line (if it already present, separate `nokaslr` with space and make sure to enclose the whole kernel command line with quotes if needed, as required by your shell).

If this is not your case, then chances are in your VM an emulated BIOS starts the bootloader (probably, GRUB) that loads actual kernel. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time), it may be necessary to hold Shift at VM boot to get to the boot menu. If so, GRUB allows user to (AFAIK, **temporarily**) edit boot parameters. On my Ubuntu 17.04 with GRUB 2.02, I need to press "e" on a menu entry I want to edit. Then I find a `linux` command followed by something like `/boot/vmlinuz...` and kernel command line -- just put `nokaslr` at the end of that line and press Ctrl-x to boot.

Comment: Can setting `kernel.randomize_va_space=0` in `/ect/sysctl.conf` be helpful?

Comment: @SomeName IIUC `kernel.randomize_va_space=0` affects **userspace processes** started after that sysctl variable was set and `nokaslr` changes how the **kernel itself** is loaded. Moreover, I doubt randomization can be enabled/disabled in an automatic and reliable way *after* the process/kernel was loaded (load addresses could be used in lots of computations at that time), so implementing a runtime switch for KASLR should probably be much more work than implementing `nokaslr` boot parameter, if possible at all.